# Doing Arithmetic on VARCHAR columns

Tags: mysql

The 3 fields below 'Winning', 'BuyIn', 'ChampFund' are VARCHAR datatype with values that include a $ character like $250.00

Example of the result I'm looking for:

'Winnings' - 'BuyIn' - 'ChampFund' As 'Net'
   $250    -   $45   -     $5      =  $200

If they were  INT datatype I would

```
Select *, Winnings - BuyIn - ChampFund As Net From gamedetail
```

Any suggestion as to how to accomplish this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply should not store numeric data in string columns.  THis is a very bad idea.

But, you can easily do what you want, because MySQL will convert string to numbers in a numeric context.  Something like:

```
select (replace(replace(Winnings, '$', ''), ',', '') -
        replace(replace(BuyIn, '$', ''), ',', '') -
        replace(replace(ChampFund, '$', ''), ',', '')
       )
```

I've included comma in the logic, because often when a currency symbol is present, so are thousands-separators.  Also, you shouldn't put column names in single quotes, but that might just be how you asked the question.

Comment: The database was already existing, and not designed by me. Thank you I will give it a try.